# check if input/value in b-form-selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `b-form-select` and when I choose one option I want to enable my button. But I don't know how to check if there is a value in my selection.

Thanks for helping me out !

```
<b-form-select v-model="data.Name" :value="data.Name"></b-form-select>

<b-button :disabled="!validDataAdded"></b-button>
```

```
computed: {
  validDataAdded: function(){
    return //Check here
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer that question first we need to make some things clear.

 `v-model` uses the `:value` attribute under the hood as a way to communicate with the component and pass down values. 
That been said you dont need to add a `:value` attribute to your select component. If you need to set a initial value you simply need to set an initial value to your `v-model`.

If you want to check if there is a value to your selection you just need to check if the `v-model` has a value. Remember that a `v-model` corresponds to a property (either part of `data` or `computed` section).

 In you example you need to check if `data.Name` contains a value or not.

 Check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mi4yq) where I create an example for you according you code-snippet.

 Last but not least the way that you have written your `v-model` it seems that you have an object called data inside your `data` property